# Style attributes doesn't work on Input with suffix or prefix

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, antd

setting  Style attributes is working with that.

```
 <Input
      style={{ borderWidth: this.state.focused ? "4px" : "1px" }}
      placeholder="this works"
      onMouseEnter={() => this.setState({ focused: true })}
      onMouseLeave={() => this.setState({ focused: false })}
    />
```

However, when I use the suffix or prefix attribute of [Input](https://ant.design/components/input/) component, It doesn't work.

```
    <Input
          style={{ borderWidth: this.state.focused ? "4px" : "1px" }}
          placeholder="not this"
          /*only difference is this suffix line*/
          suffix={<Icon type="save" />}
          onMouseEnter={() => this.setState({ focused: true })}
          onMouseLeave={() => this.setState({ focused: false })}
        />
```

When I check the source codes on browser, It gives me the reason.

**1.case :**

```
<input placeholder="this works" type="text" class="ant-input" style="border-width: 1px;">
```

**2.case :**

```
<span class="ant-input-affix-wrapper" style="border-width: 1px;"><input placeholder="not this" type="text" class="ant-input"><span class="ant-input-suffix"><i class="anticon anticon-save"></i></span></span>
```

the reason for 2. case span block absorbs the style.

[running demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/z6w2q36lp)

So How can I set my style on a input that has a suffix/prefix attribute.

Answer (score 1):

`style` property on `input` with `suffix` or `prefix` property isn't supported in the implementation of Input component.

See https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/3.10.7/components/input/Input.tsx#L170

```
{prefix}
{React.cloneElement(children, { style: null, className: this.getInputClassName() })}
{suffix}
```

You can work around this by passing `className` property for the `Input` component.

Say you have these CSS definitions in a stylesheet,

```
.border-sm input, input.border-sm {
  border-width: 1px;
}

.border-lg input, input.border-lg {
  border-width: 4px;
}
```

Your implementation for the `Input`s can look like so:

```
//...
import "./style.css"

class ErrorExample extends React.Component {
  //...

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Enter mouse into one of textboxes</h1>
        <Input
          className={this.state.focused ? "border-lg" : "border-sm"}
          //...
        />
        <Input
          className={this.state.focused ? "border-lg" : "border-sm"}
          suffix={<Icon type="save" />}
          //...
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is the style is created dynamically, so I can not write the attributes on CSS file.  Therefore, It doesn't solve my problem :/